# query optimization for many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

i have some data like this :

1. home 1

   1.record 1

   2.record 2

   3.record 3
2. home 2

   1.record 2_1

   2.record 2_2
3. home 3

   1.record 3_1

and i have three table identity and identityField and IdentityFieldValue

```
[sqlServer 2012]

identity 
  identityId

identityField 
  identityFieldid

IdentityFieldValue
   identityId
   identityFieldid
   value
```

how to fetch records with a one query  and use with two for loop ???

```
for(home in homes)
{
   for(field in home.fields)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: The relationship between the home/records and the identity* tables is unclear. Could you explain?

Comment: i stored homes in identity and stored home properties in identityfield like bed , bath ,.... and in identityfieldvalue store something like this home 1 , bed , 3 (with id's)

Comment: each home has some field and i want fetch them in one query

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to know what you're looking for with the limited amount of data provided, is this what you need?

```
SELECT *
FROM identity ID

INNER JOIN IdentityFieldValue IFLV
ON IFLV.identityId = ID.identityId

INNER JOIN identityField IFL
ON IFL.identityFieldid = IFLV.identityFieldid
```

Comment: I was answering something like that, so I guess we're on the same page in page of understanding the issue :)
@Fadakar: If that's what you are looking for, you might want to change your database design. From the information we have, there is no reason for IdentityField and IdentityFieldValue tables: they should be replaced by fields in the Identity table.